# Google Analytics Funnel showing zero when Goal Funnel is showing data

Tags: google-analytics, data-visualization, universal-analytics, web-analytics, graph-visualization

I have an issue with my Funnel Visualization in Google Analytics where the funnels are showing as zero for every step - even although the Goal Funnel report just above it shows a conversion rate for that goal.

I have Funnel as 'ON' for this goal, but it is not showing anything.

Am I misunderstanding something about funnels here or is my setup wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to simply be a case of waiting for the funnel reports to populate. I was under the impression that they would be populated in a matter of hours, but in this case it was 24hrs+.